# How can I quickly insert test data into BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Inserting large amounts of test data into BigQuery can be slow, especially if the exact details of the data aren't important and you just want to test the performance of a particular shape of query/data.

What's the best way to achieve this without waiting around for many GB of data to upload to GCS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I'd recommend testing over small amounts of data (to save money and time).

If you really need large amounts of test data, there are several options.

If you care about the exact structure of the data:

- You can upload data to GCS in parallel (if a slow single transfer is the bottleneck).
- You could create a short-lived Compute Engine VM and use it to insert test data into GCS (which is likely to provide higher throughput than over your local link). This is somewhat involved, but gives you a very fast path for inserting data generated on-the-fly by a script.

If you just want to try out the capabilities of the platform, there are a number of public datasets available for experimentation. See:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sample-tables

If you just need a large amount of data and duplicate rows are acceptable:

You can insert a moderate amount of data via upload to GCS. Then duplicate it by querying the table and appending the result to the original. You can also use the bq command line tool with copy and the --append flag to achieve a similar result without being charged for a query.

This method has a bit of a caveat -- to get performance similar to typical production usage, you'll want to load your data in reasonably large chunks. For a 400GB use case, I'd consider starting with 250MB - 1GB of data in a single import. Many tiny insert operations will slow things down (and are better handled via the streaming API, which does the appropriate batching for you).